# USB hub and the identification of positions

Tags: usb, libusb

I need to attach 8 devices of the same kind (RFID readers) to the 8 positions of the USB hub. I need to recognize which reader is not plugged-in. I also need to know which exact device sends the data (based on the physical location)

I am aware of "a path" related to an USB plug. However, I am still a newbie in the topic. Are the positions at the USB hub numbered always the same way, or are the numbers in the path assigned based on when the USB device is plugged in? In other words, can I tell whether a specific position at the USB hub is connected or not? Can I reliably determine which device sends the data based on the communication path?

Comment: USB serial numbers (iSerialNumber) are usualy used to distiguish one device from another of the same type. Or your devices have no unique serial? Relying on the usb port chain/path is a bad idea, user may plug a usb hub in the different port and get different numbers.

Comment: @Flexz: As far as I know the USB serial number is related to flash drives only -- or possibly only to some other devices.